# Mapforce: merging changes in Perforce version control

Tags: xslt, version-control, perforce

In my project I am using mapforce to create XSLT transforms. The problem is that mapforce generates different output even after a minor change (different var names, different object sequence etc.)
If I implement some functionality in, say, Project branch 1.2 and other developer adds another functionality in branch 1.3, and we both submit changes to branches 1.2 and 1.3 respectively, there is no way one can just integrate changes (I am using Perforce for version control) to version 1.3, it has to be reimplemented.
Is there anyway I could overcome this? Maybe a version control plug-in in mapforce?

Comment: Can you show (small) snippets of Mapforce output (before and after minor edits)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is just a limitation of code generators.  Most just assign new labels (or numbers) as they go along, so depending on where the added code is, *everything* generated after that point will be changed.

To fix it, the MapForce code generator would have to save the metadata used when generating code, and re-use it the next time you generate code.  The generator would have to distinguish new items from those that have just moved, and re-use all existing ones.  It *might* be a major change to their software to do this, depending on how it is currently implemented.

It can't hurt to request/suggest such a feature, and having it would help Altova position Mapforce as more of a production-ready solution, able to support version control of the customer's work.